# nopcommerce Getting the values from the bulk product edit form in the action

Tags: c#, forms, filter, action, nopcommerce

Ok so I have the action filter working, but I'm not sure how to pull the values from the bulk edit form.

I have registered the filter in dependancy registrar.

Here is my filter:

```
using Nop.Admin.Controllers;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Nop.Plugin.Feed.Froogle.Actions
{
    public class BulkEditOverideActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IFilterProvider
    {
        public IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
        {
            if (controllerContext.Controller is ProductController && actionDescriptor.ActionName.Equals("BulkEditUpdate", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                return new List<Filter>() { new Filter(this, FilterScope.Action, 0) };
            }
            return new List<Filter>();
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The filter action is = " + filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName.ToString());
            if (filterContext != null)// && amazonListingActive == true
            {
                var form = (FormCollection)filterContext.ActionParameters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "form").Value;
                foreach (var i in form.Keys)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The key value is = " + i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyone know how I might accompluish this.

Comment: What do you want specifically?

Comment: @div see my answer for what I meant, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out.
The form returns a namevaluecollection, so had to use this to get the values.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
        var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
        if (httpContext != null && httpContext.Request.Form.HasKeys())
        {

            var form = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Form;
            var products = form.AllKeys.SelectMany(form.GetValues, (k, v) => new { key = k, value = v });
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The form is = " + form);

            if (form != null)
            {
                foreach (var pModel in products)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The pModel.Key is = " + pModel.key);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The pModel.Value is = " + pModel.value);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

> UPDATE This is why I did it this way and couldn't use request form.
>
> I have a product save event, which I use to save info in a additional
>   product edit tab I created. In there I can use request form like so.
>
> ```
> public class ProductSaveConsumer : IConsumer<EntityFinalised<Product>>
> {
>     public void HandleEvent(EntityFinalised<Product> eventMessage)
>     {
>         var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
>         if (httpContext != null) {
>             amazonProduct = new AmazonProduct();
>             var form = httpContext.Request.Form;
>             //now I can grab my custom form values
>             if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(form["AmazonProductSKU"]))
>                 amazonProduct.AmazonProductSKU = form["AmazonProductSKU"].ToString();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> But the bulk edit filter returns a NameValueCollection, So I couldn't
>   use `Request.Form`

Hope this helps someone else :)

Comment: Couldn't you just cast the Request.Form to keyvaluepair enumerable?

Comment: @Raphael See my updated answer, I tried that first :)